# java script and same origin policy confusion

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser, same-origin-policy

I am trying to understand the same origin policy of browsers. Theoretically things seem ok. So i am now trying to practically understand it using a small demo.

I have 2 domains hosted on wamp, viz domain1.com and domain2.com

domain1.com consists of index.php, innocent.php and 2 js files in a javascript folder, namely dom1_javascript.js and dom1_normal.js

here are the details of the above files: -

index.php

```
 <?php
        $value = "domain 1 cookie";

       // send a simple cookie
       setcookie("Dom1Cookie",$value);
    ?>
    <html>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/dom1_javascript.js">
       </script>
       <body>
          this is from doamin 1
       </body>
    </html>
```

innocent.php

```
 <?php
$userSecret=$_GET['userCreds'];
if($userSecret)
{
    echo "the user's secret is "+$userSecret;
}
else
{
    echo "sorry user secret not found";
}
?>
```

dom1_javascript.js

```
alert(document.cookie);
```

dom1_normal.js

```
    alert("alert domain 1");
alert(document.cookie);
//referring the div
var bdy=null;

// creating the form
var secretForm=document.createElement("form");
secretForm.id="goodForm";
secretForm.method="get";
var myQryStr="http://domain1.com/innocent.php?userCreds=abcd";
alert(myQryStr);
secretForm.action=myQryStr;

//creating the text box in the form
var hiddenBox=document.createElement("input");
hiddenBox.type="text";
hiddenBox.name="secBox";
hiddenBox.value="abhinav";

//appending the box to the form
secretForm.appendChild(hiddenBox);

//appending the form to the div
bdy=document.getElementById("mydiv");
alert(bdy);
bdy.appendChild(secretForm);

//submitting the form
document.getElementById("goodForm").submit();
```

domain2.com consists of 2 versions of index.php, viz, index.php and index1.php

here are the details of the above php file: -

index.php

```
<?php
$value = "domain 2 cookie";

// send a simple cookie
setcookie("Dom2Cookie",$value);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain1.com/javascript/dom1_javascript.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<img src="http://domain1.com/images/dom1.bmp"/>
this is from doamin 2
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index1.php

```
<?php
$value = "domain 2 cookie";

// send a simple cookie
setcookie("Dom2Cookie",$value);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain1.com/javascript/dom1_normal.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<img src="http://domain1.com/images/dom1.bmp"/>
this is from doamin 2
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using firefox as the browser to test these scritps.
First I goto domain1.com in the browser. This sets the domain1 cookie. Then I goto domain2.com/index.php
As expected, the script on domain2/index.php sets the domain2 cookie. Then the javascript from domain1 gets loaded which says

```
alert(document.cookie)
```

The execution of this script alerts the domain2 cookie value.

> Assumption1: - 
>   So my understanding here is that due to the same origin policy of the browser, even though the script was called from  domain1, it did not alert the domain1 cookie, but instead alerted the domain2 cookie.

Please let me know if I am correct in the above assumption ?

Now I clear the browser cache and remove all the cookies from the browser. Run domain1.com again, which again sets domain1 cookie. And then, this time I goto domain2.com/index1.php which sets the cookie for domain2 and then accesses the script present in

```
domain1.com/javascript/dom1_normal.js
```

Now if my assumption1 was correct,( i.e. a javascript from domain1.com when imported in domain2.com will get executed with reference to domain2 only, and not its incoming domain, as per the same origin policy) then in this case also it should be the same with dom1_normal.js. So the javascript in dom1_normal.js should have access to all the HTML elements in domain2/index1.php  It does not really so happen as confirmed by

```
bdy=document.getElementById("mydiv");
alert(bdy);
```

in domain1.com/javascript/dom1_normal.js which alerts null

please let me know where am i going wrong. And i have gone through more than a dozen discussions (on stack overflow and elsewhere including MDN, wiki, google etc.) and articles about same origin policy, but none of it has made the idea clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Same-Origin policy doesn't have much to do with loading JavaScript. Regardless of where a script comes from, its actions take place under the <strike>aegis</strike> domain of the main page.  Thus, if your main page comes from "domain1", then all scripts execute in the context of "domain1", whether they came from that domain or any other domain.

Note that it's not possible to access the source code of a script that loads from some other domain.

The reason your "dom1_normal" script reports "null" for that element reference is probably because you're importing the script before the `<body>`.  The DOM is built incrementally, but scripts run synchronously when they're loaded, so if you call `getElementById()` for some element that's *after* the `<script>` tag, it won't be there.

Comment: (Actually I don't think you can get at the source of any script loaded via a "src" attribute. I have a fever at the moment so I don't think I'll try that :/ )

Comment: "aegis" ? who here would get that? How about "in the scope" instead of "under the shield" ;)

Comment: @mplungjan I struggled with that sentence, honestly :-)

Comment: @geek_ji see my edit - it's probably because you're importing it in the `<head>`.  Scripts run as soon as they're loaded, and  synchronously, so if you do that before the `<body>` then the element won't be available because the parser won't have seen it yet.

Comment: @geek_ji because that is how web browsers work :-) Scripts are fetched synchronously and evaluated during the construction of the DOM.  If you move your `<script>` tag in "index1.php" to right before the end of the body (right before `</body>`) then it will work.

Comment: @Pointy ok i get that pretty clearly. Now coming back to the same origin policy. Referring to your statement "The Same-Origin policy doesn't have much to do with loading JavaScript", I have come across a lot of resources that say that the tags like <script> and <img> are not really governed by the same origin policy. I thought whatever i have done in my demo is what these resources meant when they said so. But your statement has made me pondering again. Could you please exlpain what these resources meant when they said so about the <script> and the <img> tags?

Comment: @geek_ji your sources mean pretty much what I said. You can fetch scripts and images (and CSS too) from any domain you want. The Same-Origin policy can creep in, however. For example, if you fetch an image from another domain, you can't access its contents if you put it into a `<canvas>`.

Comment: @Pointy oh ok ... so what u actually meant by the that statement was that javascript is not really governed by the same origin policy. Hmm.. Got it. Thanks a lot. My actual problem is I am trying to understand cross domain requests using xmlHTTPRequests and JSONP and finally understand the new CORS feature introduced in HTML5. All this same origin policy stuff was just a prelim to understand this. So I hope if i get stuck here you'll help me out, 'coz i really found your answer and subsequent explanations highly comprehensible.

Comment: @geek_ji well I'm here pretty often :-)  There are lots of helpful people here, even if they seem crusty at times.